# Siempre va a index, se dañó el routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, rutas

En un controlador me funcionan bien las rutas, puedo llenar un formulario y llegar a post para procesar, pero en otro controlador tengo el formulario en el inicio, en index, al llenar los datos no va a post sino que va a index nuevamente, incluso le puse

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CrearSolicitud", "Solicitudes", FormMethod.Post))
```

pero sigue yendo a index. Hasta eliminé index y cree una parte en el controlador Solicitud con lo mismo en el controlador y en la vista, pero sigue yento a la misma vista

Controlador

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Solicitudes
        public ActionResult Solicitud() //En el inicio se puso el inicio del proceso con las vacaciones
        {
            return View();
        } 

        // GET: 
        public ActionResult CrearSolicitud() //En el inicio se puso el inicio del proceso con las vacaciones
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: 
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CrearSolicitud(Solicitudes s)
        {
```

Vista

```
@model HGRecursosHumanos4.Models.Solicitudes

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class="jumbotron">
    <div>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ims/funcionario.jpg")" height="150" width="235" hspace="25" vspace="5" style="float:left;" />
        <h1>Solicitudes</h1>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li style="font-size:small;">Recuerde que sus solicitudes quedan pendiende de aprobación al momento de enviarlas</li>
                <li style="font-size:small;">Podrá escoger un permiso para dentro de los próximos 3 meses</li>
                <li style="font-size:small;">Formato de la fecha mes/día/año, ej. 11/01/2019</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <div class="list-group">
            @Html.ActionLink("Vacaciones", "Index", "Solicitudes", null, new { @class = "list-group-item active" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Vacaciones anticipadas", "SolicitarVacacionesAnticipadas", "Solicitudes", null, new { @class = "list-group-item " })
            @Html.ActionLink("Capacitación", "SolicitarCapacitacion", "Solicitudes", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Día del empleado", "SolicitarDiaDelEmpleado", "Solicitudes", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Permisos", "SolicitarPermiso", "Solicitudes", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
            @Html.ActionLink("Actualización de datos", "Index", "Perfil", null, new { @class = "list-group-item" })
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
    <!-- ********************************************     segunda sección               ********************************************-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <h3>Vacaciones</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td> <!-- Datos que vienen de sap -->
                <td>Cédula</td>
                <td>Correo</td>
                <td>Cargo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pedro Antonio Suarez Mira</td>
                <td>101258951</td>
                <td>pa1978@gmail.com</td>
                <td>Instrumentador quirúrgico</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
        <hr />

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" align="center">Período en que se ganó el derecho</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fecha De Inicio</td>
                    <td>Fecha De Finalización</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Días disponibles</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01/05/2016</td>
                    <td>01/04/2017</td>
                    <td colspan="2">5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01/04/2017</td>
                    <td>01/03/2018</td>
                    <td colspan="2">10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01/03/2018</td>
                    <td>01/02/2019</td>
                    <td colspan="2">15</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@*using (Html.BeginForm("CrearSolicitud", "Solicitudes", FormMethod.Post))*@
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" class="Filtros form-control input-sm" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Actualización
Cambié el nombre y ahora entra de Solicitud get a solicitud post (Siendo Solicitud el que al principio era index), sin embargo, creé otra vista con get y post y sigue llevando a la que era la página maestra.

```
// GET: Solicitudes
        public ActionResult SolicitarDiaDelEmpleado()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SolicitarDiaDelEmpleado(Solicitudes s)
        {
            try
```

El url es raro, sólo muestra el controlador, no la vista:

```
http://localhost:55935/Solicitudes
```

Y sale

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo desifré, resulta que cambié el Index para mostrar un menú y meter un formulario, Index es usado por defecto para mostrar un listado cuando y ahí ve uno cuando algo se agrega, como lo había cambiado, por eso no me daba cuenta. Osea que volver siempre a Index era lo correcto según como viene VS

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            // GET: Solicitudes
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult Index2()
            {
                return View(db.Solicitudes.ToList());
            }

            //Get
            public ActionResult Solicitud()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Solicitud(Solicitudes s)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {                 

                        s.FechaFinal = DateTime.Now;
                        s.FechaYHoraSolicitud = DateTime.Now;
                        s.Id = "e17cba68-0a0b-4d6e-abaf-8026cb91fcd1";
                        s.fk_tipo_transaccion = 3;
                        s.fk_estado_solicitud = 1;
                        db.Solicitudes.Add(s);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Message = "Solicitud guardada";
                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
                    }
                    return View("ModelStateError");
                }
                //catch
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //throw ex;
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
```